# Can I reference italics in academic writing?

Tags: formatting, academic-writing, poetry, text-analysis

I am analysing a poetry collection for college and one poem is 'Unbearable Weight of Staying' by Warsan Shire. She includes both regular and italicised type in the text, e.g:

> I don't know when love became elusive.
> *My mother's laughter in a dark room.*

Would it be appropriate to refer to the impact the italics has on readers (for example, how it conveys two voices and furthers a theme of duplicity)? Or focus purely on the words rather than the formatting? I have scoured my specification (*AQA Eng. Lit. A Level, Spec. B, Component 3*) for an answer but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything intentionally done in the poem is part of its structure.  Italics vs. regular text are clearly done for effect.  These are reasonable elements to discuss.